# Appium is not able to identify elements on a screen even though they were initialized using initElements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

## Scenario:

I am launching app on real device
Doing login
Landing on Home screen 
Home screen elements are not being identified by the appium in ANDROID device. I have tried to tap on help icon on top right.

**Note** that performing actions on any of the Home screen element is intermittent

**What I have tried:**
- Putting wait after i login.
- returning home page object after i login
- putting More wait before i use 'initElements' to initialize home page objects.
- inside home page constructor i have tried findElementsById, findElementById, i have tried putting dynamic wait of element before calling initElements
- have tried ids for all elements
- have tried xpath for all elements
- have tried to kill app and relaunch app and again tried to identify elements 
- have tried JavascriptExecutor
- Have tried tap method

//*Below is the constructor of Home page object screen which gets called after i login.*

```
public HomePageObjectsNew(Config testConfig) {
        this.testConfig = testConfig;       
        PlatformName = testConfig.getRunTimeProperty("platformNameMobile");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

List<MobileElement> abc= MobileActions.findElementsById(testConfig, "frag_home_help_imgview_id");
testConfig.logComment(Integer.toString(abc.size()));
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(testConfig.driver, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);

    }

//*Login Method:*
public HomePageObjectsNew loginFlowUsingPassword() {
        swipeWalkthroughScreens();
        enterAlreadyExistingEmailID("coios6@yopmail.com");
        Browser.wait(testConfig, 2);
        MobileActions.waitForVisibility(testConfig, txtFldPassword, 
        "Password field");
        enterPassword();
        clickOnLogin();
        Browser.wait(testConfig, 4);
        return new HomePageObjectsNew(testConfig);

    }

//*My test case:*
@Test(description = "Verify successful Login of an existing now merchant using password flow", dataProvider = "GetMobileTestConfig", timeOut = 700000)
    public void verifyPaymentRequestButtonIsClickableAfterLogin(Config testConfig) {
        try {
            LoginSignUpPageObjects loginSignUpPageObjects = new LoginSignUpPageObjects(testConfig);
            HomePageObjectsNew obj = loginSignUpPageObjects.loginFlowUsingPassword();
            obj.btnHelpScreenHeader.click();
            MobileActions.goBack(testConfig);
            obj.clickOnHamburgerMenu();
            Browser.wait(testConfig, 2);
            obj.clickOnHamburgerMenu();
            loginSignUpPageObjects.clickOnRequestPayment();
            System.out.println("Request Button clicked");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            testConfig.logFail("verifyPaymentRequestButtonIsClickableAfterLogin failed !!");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

**Actual:** Not able to click on Home screen elements 
So if i try 10 times only 1 time it works ... NOTE that id's are not dynamic have already confirmed with DEV !!

**Expected:** I should be able to click on home page elements
```

**Appium Logs:**
[MJSONWP (6fbddb32)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElements() with args: ["id","com.payu.payunow:id/frag_home_help_imgview_id","6fbddb32-3ee5-4237-beee-c0496d88e69e"]
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 5000 ms for condition
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.payu.payunow:id/frag_home_help_imgview_id","context":"","multiple":true}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"com.payu.payunow:id/frag_home_help_imgview_id","context":"","multiple":true}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.payu.payunow:id/frag_home_help_imgview_id' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: true
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.payu.payunow:id/frag_home_help_imgview_id]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=com.payu.payunow:id/frag_home_help_imgview_id]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.payu.payunow:id/frag_home_help_imgview_id]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.payu.payunow:id/frag_home_help_imgview_id' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: true

Comment: Can you post appium logs as well?

Comment: Hello Manish, welcome to stack overflow. A small suggestion: it's better to put that new info in your question instead of comments. It will give the new information more visibility, thus helping you to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait until the element is enabled. You can use the **WebDriverWait** class. `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(<element_locator>), <your_timeout>));`

Comment: i have tried that already .. its not working ..note that the issue i am facing is intermittent ..that is sometimes element is clicked sometimes its not ...so success rate is 2 out of 10